# Change a column of a table based on a filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a filter containing City/Country :

[image]

I created a table Filters with a column Filtering containing City and Country like above.

When selecting City I want to display the target by city:

[image]

When selecting Country I want to display the target by country:

[image: amirabedhiafi_2-1634393001899.png]

Knowing that I have other filters in the same page like semester ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your example, one way to achieve this output is to use Matrix visual instead of a Table visual.

- Add Target in Rows field
- Country & City in both "Columns" and "Values" fields

Comment: What about the filter that will show different visual each time ?

Comment: For dynamic filtering, I first check [SelectedValue\(\)](https://dax.guide/selectedvalue/) . If you really need to more, you may need `calculation groups`

Comment: The matrix will work with filter by default. If you don't have any filter both columns will be visible. And based on what you filter, other columns will be hidden.